# FedAuth Token not Expiring with Custom Login

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, custom-login-page

I am trying to login a user into SharePoint 2010 using C#.

This logs the user in correctly, but creates a FedAuth token that does not expire. On the SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication method that last parameter is "false" is the isPersistant parameter.

I tried setting the tokenGS1.validTo property but that is apparently read-only.

Anyone have an idea about how to get this token to expire correctly?

```
SecurityToken tokenGS1 = null;       
SPIisSettings iisSettings = IisSettings;

Uri appliesTo = new Uri(siteAddress.ToString());
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) ||
      string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
      return null;
SPFormsAuthenticationProvider authProvider = iisSettings.FormsClaimsAuthenticationProvider;

tokenGS1 = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(
            appliesTo,
            authProvider.MembershipProvider,
            authProvider.RoleProvider,
            userName,
        password,
        false);


EstablishSessionWithToken(tokenGS1);

try
{
    URLSource = Request.QueryString["Source"].ToString();
}
catch (Exception qstr)
{
    URLSource = "https://somewebsite/";
}

Response.Redirect(URLSource);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The EstablishSessionWithToken(tokeGS1) function had a method that created the token as a sessiontoken.